# How to set message timers going through SNS topic and routed to the subscribed SQS queues?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I am not sure this is possible so I just writing my question here. I am working with SNS/SQS architecture where messages going through an SNS topic and then being delivered to SQS queues that are subscribed to that topic. I want to set timers on some specific message. Is it possible to do it when they routed by the SNS topic to the SQS queue?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible, especially since you only want it "on some specific message".

There is a default Delay setting on an SQS queue, but that would not be applicable for some messages only.

There is no capability to specify Delay settings on a message going from Amazon SNS to Amazon SQS. Your only choice might be to send it to a different queue using [Amazon SNS Message Filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-filtering.html).